# Why I cannot click on the link when the width of browser shrinks?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for my CSS.

Now I've just added "Tweet button" on very right side of Navigator.
It looks fine but I encountered weird problem.

It is clickable when the width of navigation is wide enough but it won't let me click almost all the links when it's short.
Why does this happen? and is there any way to solve this?

I made [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/th2B2/) so check this please.
Please try shrink and spread the width of navigation and see whether if the links are clickable.
Thanks!

**It's clickable with this width**

[image: clickable]

**It's not clickable with this width**

[image]

**HTML**

```
          <body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>



            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#A">A</a></li>             
                    <li><a href="#B">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#C">C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#D">D</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#E">E</a></li>             
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="nav pull-right">

                　
                    <div class="btn-group"><a href="/user/a"><img alt="Avatar" src="no.png" style="width: 28px; height: 28px; border; border:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);margin-right: 2px;" /></a>
                        <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        A<span id="message_received_count_navi"></span>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                        <li><a href="/users/edit">EDIT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/visitor">VISITOR</a></li>

                        <li><a href="/messages/received">
                            messages
                        </a></li>

                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/logout">logout</a>       
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    Tweet
                    </button>

            </div>      



</div>



    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tweet</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/A/comments" class="new_comment" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_comment" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="k4DbdSOK9IZy2hJ1xqH4SGuJDrHN92nNznuZAMC2B44=" /></div>
                    <textarea autocomplete="off" class="chat_box" cols="40" id="body_input" name="comment[body]" rows="20" style="width:98%;height:100px;">
</textarea>
                        <span class="btn btn-file"><input id="comment_comment_icon" name="comment[comment_icon]" type="file" /></span>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tweet</button>
</form>       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JordanD Can't you see it's unclickable when the width of navigator is short?

Comment: its beacues when you shrink it textarea is positioned above these links

Comment: Actually I can click it, put the mouse in the top right corner of the button.

Comment: Because of your textarea#body_input.chat_box...inspect the element.

Comment: What would be the easiest and best way to solve this? Can anyone show me an answer?

Comment: @JordanD you cant click if you minimisze

Comment: @user3127499 I can click the tweet button at any size.

Comment: To know the correct problem use inspect element and hover the mouse above the navigation and the will be identified

Comment: @user3127499 I'm not supposed to use modal dialog when it has some contents and links below the modal where it shows appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problem with your model dialog window . Please check this code. This dialog window overlapping when sceen size getting small. If you can do top:40% for this dialog problem get solved.

css:

```
.modal.fade {
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
top: 40%;
}
```

×
            Tweet
          
          

                
                    
                        
          
          
            cancel
            Tweet

Answer (score 0):

Because this

```
<span class="window_label" style="opacity: 0.3;">Result</span>
```

has been positioned absolutely and is sitting on top of the button so the mouse click can't get through.

You will need to find another way of positioning it out of the way.

Comment: Thanks!! what would be the best way then?